# setFullYear adds 1 hour - explanation needed

Tags: javascript, date

Please help me understand discrepancy in the expected result vs. reality when I try to increase a year for a date by using `.setFullYear()` (or `.setUTCFullYear()` - same result).

**Setup:**

```js
let timestamp = '2010-10-12T12:00:00Z';
const initialDate = new Date(timestamp);
const resultingDate = new Date(initialDate.setFullYear(2020));

console.log('timestamp    : ' + timestamp);
console.log('initialDate  : ' + initialDate.toISOString())
console.log('resultingDate: ' + resultingDate.toISOString())
```

**Expectations:**

```
expect(resultingDate).toEqual(new Date('2020-10-12T12:00:00Z'));
```

**Reality:**

```
resultingDate === new Date('2020-10-12T13:00:00Z')
```

**Question:**

How on Earth did I get one hour increase in the result? I only set years. Or did I?

Comment: Dunno about the extra 1 hour, but FYI `setFullYear` mutates the `initialDate`. So your `initialDate` should be equal to the `resultingDate`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear

Comment: Thanks, I know. The focus of the story is on the resulting '13' instead of '12'. If I wipe off the time (by `new Date(new Date(dateStart).toISOString().substr(0,10))`) - the result becomes `...T01:00...`

One hour gain - where does it come from?

Comment: You can't compare dates like that. What if you print `initialDate`, does that also have +1 hour?

Comment: Update:
If the `initialDate`'s year is 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, etc. then setting to 2020 doesn't affect the time.
However, if the year is 2014 and below (2013, 2012, etc..) then this operation increases the time by 1 hour.

Comment: No, it doesn't ... **but I'm not in the same timezone as you** - were there DST changes in your timezone?

Comment: Your issue is likely that you start with a UTC timestamp, but set the local year. Consider using *setUTCFullYear*. The issue doesn't occur for me.

Comment: What *value* exactly does it give you? Probably your local timezone, not `Z`. The reason for the discrepancy then is that the timezone rules changed between 2010 and 2020 for your local timezone.

Comment: In my time zone I've this result between 1994 and 1995 because winter time in 1994 occured in september, and from 1995 it occurs in october. Check if you have a change in DST's in your timezone between 2010 and now !

Comment: @iguypouf  See the link in my answer.  Moscow stopped using DST in 2014.  My suggestion there is to use `Date.UTC(...)` to construct dates as this ignores the timezone of the user and bases dates/times solely on UTC time.

Comment: Indeed, I should have thought of the location (Moscow, Russia) and its influence for the time (after all, one hour exactly should have clicked), and indeed, "On 1 July 2014, the State Duma passed a bill partially repealing the 2011 change, putting Moscow Time on permanent UTC+03:00 and thus back to standard time."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to what happened to Moscow time in 2014.  See: [Moscow timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Time)

Effectively, Moscow changed from UTC+4 to UTC+3 on 26/10/2014.  So, on 12/10/2010, 16:00 in Moscow was 12:00 in UTC time.  But, from 2015, 16:00 in Moscow was 13:00 in UTC time.  So, dates up to 2014 will show 12:00 and dates after that will show 13:00.

Comment: You could try using [Date.UTC(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) to construct your date as that makes no reference to local timezoning.